# binlog_do_db groups for mysql replication?

Tags: mysql, security, replication, binlog

Is it possible to split the binlog_do_db to slave-groups?

I have a mysql master server with the databases "frontend, backend, events, lists".

Now I want to replicate the databses "events and lists" to slave 1 and slave 2.

For a live backup I want to replicate all databases to slave 3.

I know that I can simply add binlog_do_db=frontend,backend,events,lists to my master config file.

But I have security concerns about the binary log file. As I understood the replication, an attacker at slave 1 or slave 2 is able to read then also the datas from frontend, backend and events by opening the relay log file "mysqlbinlog mysqld-relay-bin.00000X".

So is it possible to create "binlog_do_db"-groups to restrict the binarylog transfer?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can create an intermediate server with `BLACKHOLE` tables, with its only purpose filtering the logs. You could just run it on the same server: as it doesn't actually save anything in tables but just logs to binlog, it's terribly fast. So, replication is `master -> slave3` for the backup, but `master -> filtering blackhole server -> slave 1 & slave 2`.

Comment: Thank you very much, seems to be the right setup. :)